# JDBC error message (an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...)

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am playing with JDBC Driver with Java and I get the following error message:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(5) NOT NULL)' at line 1

MY SQL Syntax looks like:

```
String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE dbuser1("+"USER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL"+");";
```

It seems to me that there is no problem with my sql statement. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUMBER is not a datatype that is why you are getting a syntax error, so

Instead of

```
String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE dbuser1("+"USER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL"+");";
```

use if you want only integer values in your table

```
String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE dbuser1("+"USER_ID INTEGER(5) NOT NULL"+");";
```

or if you want to use decimal values in your table

```
 String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE dbuser1("+"USER_ID Decimal(5) NOT NULL"+");";
```

For complete list of datatypes refer to the following link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no `NUMBER(5)` datatype in MySQL, it should be `INTEGER(5)`. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html) for the documentation of all of MySQL's datatypes

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
NUMBER(5)
```

to

```
INT(5)
```

as MySQL doesnot have `NUMBER` data-type instead MySQL supports all standard SQL numeric data types. These types include the exact numeric data types (`INTEGER, SMALLINT, DECIMAL, and NUMERIC`), as well as the approximate numeric data types (`FLOAT, REAL, and DOUBLE PRECISION`).The keyword `INT` is a synonym for `INTEGER`. [Refer MySQL Numeric Data-types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)